# Highcharts: min value of y axis on the bottom of chart

Tags: highcharts

I would like some help with this chart. If the series values are not 0.0, the minimum value of the chart is 0, and it's correctly on the [bottom of the chart](http://jsfiddle.net/andrea75/NF7sF/1/):

But if the values are all equal to 0.0, the y-axis line is shown in the [middle of the chart](http://jsfiddle.net/andrea75/NF7sF/):

I try to set

```
 {min: 0,}
```

on the y-axis, but it doesn't work. Obviously I can't set a max value because I have a dynamic data. How can I solve this?

Comment: your jsfiddle is already showing it in middle for me... which browser are u using?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: The problem is that it was on the middle... I want that it show on bottom. ;) As on the example on the answer of SteveP.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you can't set a max, you can set a minRange

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            min: 0,
            minRange: 0.1,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tZayD/